# API telegram, getUpdates and webhook проблемы

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Есть проблема с ботом в телеграм. Установил вебхук (да в прочем и на getUpdates тоже самое происходит) пишу сообщение боту в личку - все отлично, делает то что ему прописано... Добавляю бота в группу, на вебхук приходит информация new_chat_members. Но когда я пишу в этом групповом чате, обновления не происходит, т.е. в GetUpdates я не вижу ни 1 сообщения, точно так же и на вебхук не приходит информация, в чем может быть дело?

UPD: Кстати когда кикаешь бота из группы информация с пометкой left_chat_member как в webhook так и в getUpdates приходит....

UPD2: getWebhookInfo:

```
{"ok":true,"result": {"url":"https://site.ru/webhook.php","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":0,"max_connections":40}}
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема решилась отключением Privacy mode в настройках бота...